# Need an explanation of strange behavior from Clojure's ns function

Tags: syntax, clojure, namespaces

I'm noticing some strange behavior from Clojure's ns function. I thought it didn't care too much about the order of its arguments, but apparently it can be extremely picky.

In one file, I have

```
(ns ^{:doc "Foobar"
      :author "me"}
  foo.bar)
```

but if I instead write it as

```
(ns foo.bar ^{:doc "Foobar"
              :author "me"})
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol
```

In other files, I have put foo.bar right after ns, and so long as the metadata isn't the last argument to ns, it runs fine. This is a little annoying, because in other files, I have some things like (:require foo.baz), which apparently *must* go after foo.bar, or else it will throw another exception. What exactly are the rules for ns? I want all of my calls to ns to be consistent, and right now I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not about `ns`, but about the lexical syntax of Clojure.

The `^{...}` syntax causes the reader to attach the given map to the result of reading the following form. So, in your example,

```
^{:doc ... :author ...} foo.bar
```

is actually read in as a single symbol `foo.bar` with the given metadata. Clearly if `^{...}` is the last thing between an ending bracket, the reader won't have anything to attach this piece of metadata to, so it will throw an exception (at read time, so before any macros are expanded etc.).

It is fairly typical in Clojure that metadata put on symbolic names in various `def`-like forms (except those which are meant purely for host interop, like `definterface`) gets transferred to the thing being defined. The basic macros (`ns`, `defn`, `defmacro`) also support an attribute map argument and a separate docstring argument:

```
(ns foo.core
  "Quite a magnificent namespace, and very well-documented."
  {:author "Alice Perr"}
  (:require [foo.protocols :refer [PFoo]]))

(defn fooify
  "Return a PFoo wrapper for x."
  {:added "0.0.1"}
  [x]
  (reify PFoo
    ...))
```

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense now. I'm used to Common Lisp, so all this new metadata syntax is a bit confusing.